# Menu to open on the visibile screen/ current location on web page whenever clicked on sticky button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a navbar which will scroll down on clicking a button. It is working fine but there is just one thing that I am unable to figure. My navbar is sticky and when I scroll down to the bottom of page or mid of page and click the button then the navbar menu is displayed at the top of webpage not at the current location where I am.

I want the navbar to behave the same way as the button in each navbar on stackoverflow that no matter where on the page I click the button, the div becomes visible.

This is the CSS code:

```
#btndiv
        {
          background-color:red;
          height: 56px;
          position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
        }

#mobilemenu
{
   display: none;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
   position: absolute; 
    width:100%;

  
}

#mobilelinks
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#mobilelinks a
{
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}
.innerdiv
{
    margin: 12px; 
} 
.links
{
    float: left;
}
.links a
{
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 0px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.links a:hover, .links a:focus
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

the work that I have done so far is displayed here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mahajaved/cans5qe0/16/

Comment: Thank you so much to all those who replied. It means a lot. My most accounts get blocked here but finally someone helped thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Working Solution :-

https://codepen.io/sbrakeshrath/pen/BaWmayY

## What was Wrong

The `#btndiv` was sticky but`#mobilemenu` not .

So that's why `mobilemenu` is rendering on top .

## Solution

move `#mobilemenu` to inside of `#btndiv`

Now Both are sticky , Problem Gone !!!!! .

Answer (score 0):

The way to think about this is the menu that opens belongs to the red menu bar you have. So you want it to be positioned based on where your menubar is. The first step is therefore to move the `#mobilemenu` div into your `#btndiv`

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7b3fg6z0/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `mobilemenu` is completely outside your div `btnDiv` that acts as the navbar. Just move the `mobilemenu` inside that div to fix your problem:

```js
function menuvisible() {
  $('#mobilemenu').slideToggle('slow');
}
```

```css
#btndiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 56px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#mobilemenu {
  display: none;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 10;
  left: 0
}

#mobilelinks {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#mobilelinks a {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}

.innerdiv {
  margin: 12px;
}

.links {
  float: left;
}

.links a {
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.links a:hover,
.links a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btndiv">
  <button id="menubtn" onclick="menuvisible()">Menu</button>

  <div id="mobilemenu">
    <div class="innerdiv links" id="mobilelinks">
      <a href="home.php#home">Home</a>
      <a href="">About</a>
      <a href="">Courses</a>
      <a href="">Library</a>
      <a href="">Services</a>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, sequi. Possimus, omnis natus. Quos, nostrum ab iste laudantium quod vitae doloribus perspiciatis quibusdam reiciendis fugit ratione nam veniam eaque vel optio possimus deserunt, fugiat laboriosam!
  A, voluptas. Itaque magnam, quasi aliquam obcaecati hic esse blanditiis deleniti repudiandae totam temporibus amet veritatis quaerat in doloribus recusandae quos eaque vero tempora rerum corporis quia culpa quas nulla. Laudantium tenetur provident voluptate
  impedit cum veritatis doloremque minima dolore modi quibusdam, cupiditate aperiam, pariatur ex voluptas magni nobis. Voluptatibus, quia error fugit quae ex placeat iusto magni provident architecto? Quisquam nam quas ea enim! Quod quidem, adipisci et
  soluta ullam voluptas rerum cupiditate eius, exercitationem, similique maxime omnis consequuntur tenetur quae maiores eos doloremque ab libero debitis? Dicta omnis sequi recusandae atque, libero quod repudiandae aut at fugiat alias earum? Eveniet corporis
  modi rerum non? Aperiam, deserunt in voluptatum quisquam velit tempora repellendus dolor laboriosam, ipsam aspernatur quidem ipsa sit magnam ab non laborum voluptate sequi. Quibusdam inventore fugiat laborum quas blanditiis earum doloremque molestias,
  neque qui et est error voluptate doloribus quasi quia ipsa ipsum voluptatibus. At est odio debitis sunt architecto quo tempore eius deserunt sed et ad molestias reiciendis impedit minus earum consequuntur, nobis dignissimos beatae expedita corporis
  atque totam doloribus nihil ipsa. Et beatae ratione, a hic odio, saepe voluptas quis necessitatibus sit dolore impedit voluptates eveniet tenetur libero fugit voluptatum reprehenderit exercitationem facere omnis ut distinctio vitae! Eius molestias et
  nostrum at vero pariatur asperiores, iusto cupiditate itaque labore ad consequatur corporis doloribus repellendus dolore ullam mollitia nihil repellat aut similique! Quis, ipsam similique quo aliquam saepe ut odio, fuga reiciendis nemo iusto provident
  optio quisquam dolore natus repudiandae ducimus possimus adipisci nulla deleniti est, tempora temporibus? Voluptates, voluptas neque quas sequi illo placeat animi voluptatibus asperiores porro in. Impedit pariatur esse est dolorum quas facilis assumenda
  laboriosam ab culpa vitae! Cum, repudiandae. Temporibus nam voluptatum esse perferendis quam expedita, dignissimos quod aliquid dolore eum consequatur laboriosam quos eius animi aliquam ipsam deserunt officia reiciendis. Harum assumenda velit molestiae
  necessitatibus aspernatur sed tempora quod.</div>
```

This works because now `mobilemenu` is a child of `btnDiv`, so when you set `position: absolute` on `mobilemenu`, you can control its position using `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`, which will be calculated **relative** to the position of `btnDiv`

Earlier, the position of `mobilemenu` was being calculated relative to its parent, which was `body` hence it was always at the top right corner of the document even when the page was scrolled down.